# Growing or descending stack

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

In the context of operating systems and processes, which design is better - A growing or descending stack [User mode/kernel mode stack] ?

Comment: Better for what? Maybe sideways is better.

Comment: "In the context of operating systems" - yes, because all operating systems have the same design goals.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon placement of the heap and library mappings; if the libraries and heap are low, then growing the stack downwards makes a lot of sense. If the libraries and heap are high, then growing the stack upwards makes a lot of sense. And both seem pretty arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 1):

From a security point of view, I prefer the stack growing upwards, as it reduces the probability of a buffer overflow attack succeeding; there are several architectures that have dedicated stack manipulation instructions that assume a particular direction, so you may not always get to choose (for example, the Motorola 68000 MOVEM intstruction has *register indirect with predecrement* mode for source and *register indirect with postincrement* mode for destination operands, but not the other way 'round).